# Export/Convert XML columns to a list format in excel csv

Tags: excel, xml, powershell, csv

Can someone help me out to convert this xml code to a list format with the desired fields? I am struggling to even see if this is possible. So far I have not found anything that can do this for me. I am hoping it is possible.

Below I have the below XML code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VShell Version="4.0">
  <VirtualRoots Type="subkey">
    <VirtualRoot Type="subkey">
      <Path Type="string"></Path>
      <Alias Type="string"></Alias>
      <Comment Type="string"></Comment>
      <MigratedPermissions Type="dword">2</MigratedPermissions>
      <Users Type="array"/>
    </VirtualRoot>
    <VirtualRoot Type="subkey">
      <Path Type="string">D:\SFTP_A</Path>
      <Alias Type="string">SFTP_A1</Alias>
      <Comment Type="string"></Comment>
      <MigratedPermissions Type="dword">2</MigratedPermissions>
      <Users Type="array">
        <Item Type="string">SFTP Users Root Users,allow,use read write deletefile list create deletedir</Item>
        <Item Type="string">FTPDan,allow,use read write deletefile list create deletedir</Item>
        <Item Type="string">SFTP_ClaireVIP,allow,use read write deletefile list create deletedir</Item>
        <Item Type="string">SFPT_ADMIN,allow,use read write deletefile list create deletedir</Item>
      </Users>
    </VirtualRoot>
    <VirtualRoot Type="subkey">
      <Path Type="string">D:\Company_Exports_SFTP</Path>
      <Alias Type="string">Company_Exports_SFTP</Alias>
      <Comment Type="string"></Comment>
      <MigratedPermissions Type="dword">2</MigratedPermissions>
      <Users Type="array">
        <Item Type="string">DOMAINA\SFTP_ADMINUSER,allow,use read list</Item>
      </Users>
    </VirtualRoot>
```

And I want this to be converted into a list in a excel csv format. The output I desire is below:

[image: Desired output]

Is there any way I could possibly do this? Preferably with a command.

Thanks

Dan

Comment: Please note that you have not submitted a complete/valid XML file, and as such we cannot work with it as reproducible. We also expect you to submit the exact format and syntax of the CSV file, not an image of how it renders when represented in your own GUI software. Please [Edit] your question and make those replacements for us.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Powershell Script

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq 

$inputFilename = "c:\temp\test.xml"
$outputFilename = "c:\temp\test.csv"
$xDoc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($inputFilename)

$virtualRoots =  $xDoc.Descendants("VirtualRoot")
$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
foreach($virtualRoot in $virtualRoots)
{
   $path = $virtualRoot.Element('Path').Value
   $alias = $virtualRoot.Element('Alias').Value
   foreach($item in $virtualRoot.Descendants('Item'))
   {
      $newRow = New-Object -TypeName psobject
      $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName 'Path Type' -NotePropertyValue $path
      $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName 'Alias Type' -NotePropertyValue $alias
      $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName 'Item Type' -NotePropertyValue $item.Value

      $table.Add($newRow) | Out-Null
   }
}
$table | format-Table
$table | Export-CSV -Path $outputFilename
```

Comment: I cannot install System.XML.Linq for some reason. Is there code I can use that doesn't install packages?

Comment: You do not need to install.  It is build into PS.  PS contains the Net Library and PS is written in Net.  In PS when using a Net Library you just need to use the entire namespace of the library.  The code should run in any version of PS.  Just put code into a text file with extension ps1.  Then open PS and type :  .\test.ps1 where test is the name of the text file.